# ASP.net: how to store array of day checkboxes into MSSQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, checkbox

Good day. MSDN says that `bit` MSSQL datatype mapping onto `bool` C# datatype. ASP.net map checkbox onto `bool`, if i currently understand. And i need to store set of checkboxes states (bool[]).

Constants.cs contains this line:

```
public static string[] Days => new string[] { "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa" };
```

View.cshtml contains this:

```
@foreach (var day in Constants.Days)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class">@day</label>
        <input name="Days" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" />
    </div>
}
```

And this, i think, will be mapped on bool[]. But here is no possible ways to store bool array in db? Or how to store set of checkboxes states in Db?

Comment: hi , you need to stored as a string array .

Comment: @RonakPatel that would be a very bad idea - how would you query that string? There's nothing wrong with using 7 bit columns

Comment: @RonakPatel e.g. "Mo,We,Th"? It is possible way, but looks strange, isn't?

Comment: Checkboxes have nothing to do with databases. What do you want to store? Alarm activation days? Use 7 columns, one for each day. Recurring  appointments? Use a single column whose value (1-7) corresponds to a day. It's impossible to help without knowing what you want to do

Comment: @Evgeniy175 actually, stuffing anything into a string is a very, very, very bad design. It breaks even the simplest database rule, and you simply *can't* query it. How would you find rows for Thursdays? What if you have 1000 rows? Would you load check *all* of them to find which one may contain a string? What if you want to seach for *two* days?  Never mind the extra problem of deciding which language and abbreviation to use

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's days when action should be performed, how i can describe more?

Comment: Then use 7 bit columns, one for each day

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh, yep, it will be really simple, if i want to find action for specific day and each day has own column! Thank you!

Comment: 7 `BIT` columns (non-`NULL`!) would be fine. You could also have separate rows for each day, though that's harder to update. Do not, if you value your sanity, use a single `VARCHAR` column or an `INT` with a bitmask ("to save space"). I've seen both these approaches in production systems and they're extremely painful to maintain.